# Are there degrees or categories of orthogonality?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

The vectors $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ b \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ c\end{bmatrix}$ are orthogonal under the dot product.

The vectors $1$, $x$, and $x^2 - 1/3$ are orthogonal under the standard inner product for polynomials, $\int_{-1}^1 p(x)q(x)\ dx$.

While both collections meet their respective definitions of orthogonality, there seems to be some sense in which the former is *more* orthogonal than the latter.

No linear combination of $1$ and $x$ produces $x^2 - 1/3$, but the combination $-1/3$ of $1$ and $1$ of $x$, yielding $x - 1/3$, appears to make some progress toward the task.  This isn't to claim that $x^2 - 1/3$ and $x - 1/3$ evaluate to similar values, but merely that if it *were* possible to reach $x^2 - 1/3$ by taking linear combinations of $1$ and $x$, this attempt would be a better start than, say, taking $-500$ of $1$ and $\pi$ of $x$.  of  By contrast, in the case of $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ b \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ c\end{bmatrix}$, it feels like no progress can be made no matter what combination is chosen.

Is there some sense in which the former, $\mathbb{R}^3$ vectors are orthogonal to a stronger degree than the latter, polynomial vectors?

Comment: How is this a progress? Could you quantify that? Speaking in terms of vector spaces, there is no difference between the two cases you gave.

Comment: I suppose it's in part the fact that polynomial degrees are ordered.  Fourth and fifth degree polynomials are clearly more intrinsically similar than second and fifth degree polynomials.  Additionally, the fact that we can construct at least one term of $x^2 - 1/3$ with the polynomial $1$ seems to constitute progress, compared to the $R^3$ case.

Comment: I suspect that whatever difference you’re sensing is a result of the relationship between the inner product and the basis that you’re using. If you take the three polynomials as your basis instead of $\{1,x,x^2\}$, then the situation looks exactly like the first one.

Comment: BTW, I might quibble about your characterization of that inner product as “_the_ standard” one. I see the integral taken from $0$ to $1$ instead at least as often.